# Android library project -exporting in jar format working in eclipse and ant but not in maven

Tags: android, maven, ant, apk, android-library

I have a android library project . I create a jar . now I copied the jar to the libs folder in a android application and build apk using eclipse and ant . the apk file is working but when I try to build using maven the apk file is not working .I have this issue from long time. 
Can you correct if I made any mistake in pom file.

pom file for android application :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.project.servicefoundation</groupId>
 <artifactId>projectservicefoundation</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>apk</packaging>
 <name>projectserviceFoundation</name>
 <dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.project.servicefoundation</groupId>
    <artifactId>androidsdk</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
   <artifactId>android</artifactId>
   <version>4.1.1.4</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
      <artifactId>android-test</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <build>
  <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
  <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
  <pluginManagement>
   <plugins>
    <plugin>
     <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
     <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>

     <version>3.5.3</version>
     <extensions>true</extensions>
    </plugin>
   </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>androidsdktests</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>
                    emulator-start
                </goal>
                <goal>
                    internal-integration-test
                </goal>
            </goals>

        </execution>
    </executions>
                <configuration>
             <sdk>
              <!-- platform or api level (api level 4 = platform 1.6) -->
              <platform>19</platform>
             </sdk>
             <emulator>
                    <avd>mydevice</avd>
                    <!-- Wait for emulator starting (3 minutes) -->
                    <wait>180000</wait>
                    <options>-no-skin</options>
                </emulator>
            </configuration>

   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

</project>
```

pom file for the android library project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.project.servicefoundation</groupId>
    <artifactId>androidsdk</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>AndroidSDK</name>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

The name of android library project is `androidsdk`.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared your dependency to `androidsdk` as `provided`, which means it will not be included in your apk (which explains why it does not work) :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.project.servicefoundation</groupId>
    <artifactId>androidsdk</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

</dependency>
```

Simply removing `<scope>provided</scope>` should do the trick.